# Entity Framework 7 no database provider is configured => when migrations are moved to another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF7. I know this is a duplicate question to:

[No database providers are configured EF7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070086/no-database-providers-are-configured-ef7)

But wait before you want to have this question closed... and read on

```
 services.AddEntityFramework()
         .AddSqlServer()
         .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services.AddScoped<TestRepository, TestRepository>();
```

Now I run the dnx ef database update command on the cmd windows in my EF project and get this error:

```
C:\TGB.DataAccess>dnx ef database update
System.InvalidOperationException: No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseProviderSelector.SelectServices(ServiceProviderSource providerSource)
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DbContextServices.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Initialize>b__0()
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.DbContextServices.get_DatabaseProviderServices()
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddEntityFramework>b__0_8(IServiceProvider p)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryService.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   bei Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(DbContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<UpdateDatabase>b__0()
   bei Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.Execute(Action action)
No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.
```

Now I tried to change the constructor of my `ApplicationDbContext` according to the solution link I pasted at the top:

Thats my code:

**My ApplicationDbContext.cs is actually empty that means nothing I have overridden.**

Looking at the base class of the base class there is the overloaded constructor with parameter DbContextOptions but I can not pass anything from my constructor?!

```
  //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   options:
        //     The options to be used by a Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.
        public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions options);
```

What is broken on my side? I am using EF 7 RC1 and dnx 451.

**This happens only when you move the ApplicationDbContext/ApplicationUser and the whole Migrations folder to an extra lets say "DataAccess" project. Then everything seems broken.**

Comment: Did you try to specify the context, eg `dnx database update -c ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: You are also able to specify the project `-p <project>`

Comment: I am in directly in the DataAccess project via CMD and I run dnx ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext => Same error as before!

Comment: I did the same for -p TGB.DataAccess => Same error as before!

Comment: I updated my question and removed my ApplicationDbContext code because I use no overloaded constructor because there is nothing to overload... and I guess that is the problem.

Comment: I created a separate project with the DbContext.
Then from the main project (the one where the EF commands are referenced) I run: ```C:\Project.Web.Api>dnx ef migrations add --targetProject Project.DataAccess Initial```
and ```C:\Project.Web.Api>dnx ef database update``` and everything seems to work just fine. The Migrations folder is created in the DataAccess project and the database is updated.
Make sure to run ```dnu restore``` command before the migration commands just in case.

Comment: My way/scenario is different: I created a project with authentication so there already exists a migrations folder in the web project which I moved to DataAccess Project. And I run the dnx ef stuff from CMD within the DataAccess project. DNX EF is recognized but I get that one error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a new ASP.NET Web Application named "WebProject" using Web Application template (Authentication: Individual User Account).
2. Now add another project to the solution named "DataAccess" (let's say Class Library type though its not relevant)
3. Now move ApplicationDbContext/ApplicationUser files & migrations folder to DataAccess project.
4. At this stage the build will be failing, so we need to correct the project.json for correct references.
5. For DataAccess project, add following dependencies

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
       "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
   }
   ```
6. For WebProject, add `DataAccess` as dependency. Since `DataAccess` has reference to above 2 packages, you can remove those references from WebProject.
   Build should succeed now and you can launch web application.

How to use ef migrations:

In command line, go to directory of WebProject (and not the DataAccess project).
All the ef commands will work fine from here.

To add new migrations to the Migrations folder of DataAccess project, you need to use `-p` flag. Like,
`dnx ef migrations add Sample -p DataAccess`.

The issue arises because the commands are run from cmd within DataAccess project. Your startup class which is initializing all the services is in WebProject. When you try to run commands from DataAccess directory, `dnx ef` will be recognized since `EntityFramework.Commands` is referenced but when you try to use the migrations, services are not initialized therefore it will fail throwing above exception.

Answer (score 5):

Try to move your Context class to your "DataAccess" project and  override the OnConfiguring method of your Context in your "DataAccess" project then run the migration.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=****;Database=***;user id=***;password=***");
    }
}
```

Or you can do like followings if you don't want to hard code your connection string. DI will inject the options for you;

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

and on your Startup.cs;

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()            
        .AddDbContext<WtContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyDb:ConnectionString"]));
}
```

and your appsetting.json;

```
{
  "Data": {
    "MyDb": {
      "ConnectionString": "**********"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: THIS public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) is NOT possible in my code, because MyContext has NO constructor with ANY parameter. Yes I inherit from DbContext!

Comment: How do you instantiate MyContext() in the Controller or wherever you need it?