# EF 7 with ASP.NET 4.51, "No database providers are configured."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this error when trying use a EF7 context in a web api 2 (asp.net 4.51) app.

> No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.

I'm using a traditional web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MemberContext" connectionString="...." 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient">
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm using ninject to inject the instance of the context.

Comment: possible duplicate:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860263/entity-framework-7-no-database-provider-is-configured-when-migrations-are-mov

Comment: @Philo no, I'm using asp.net 4.51. And I'm using ninject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{

    ...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I call that when using ninject to create the context?

Comment: this is an override in your DbContext class. I'll edit the code to show you

Comment: But nothing calls OnConfiguring because I'm using ninject

Comment: Ninject has nothing to do here. Whenever YourDbContext is instantiated, by you (new) or by Ninject, it will run this method as it's part or DbContext initialization. Actually maybe it will be called first time you execute a query more than when DbContext is initialized. Just belive :)

Comment: Progress! But it looks like I have to pass in the connection string rather than the name of the connection string. Easy enough to get, but strange.

Comment: There are some overloads of that method. But yes you are right. When I get the chance I'll correct the code

Comment: optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["MemberContext"].ConnectionString);