# C# Core MVC Ajax with Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm building an auction website, and I have a problem implementing the "Start watching" button. It is supposed to work with Ajax: adding an entity of `AuctionsUsersWatching`- a many-to-many relationship between Auctions and Users.

Controller, after being sent the ajax data (the sending works fine):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async void StartWatching( AjaxData vm)
    {

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(HttpContext.User.GetUserId());

        var auction = _context.Auctions.Where(a => a.ID == Convert.ToInt32(vm.IdAuction)).First();

        AuctionsUsersWatching tmp = new AuctionsUsersWatching()
        {
            //Auction = auction,
            AuctionId = Convert.ToInt32(vm.IdAuction),
            User = user,
            UserId = user.Id
        };
        //auction.AuctionsUsersWatching.Add(tmp);
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

After that, the last line gives me an exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll
>   but was not handled in user code

I am stuck here, what is wrong?

EDIT: 
After Jordan's comment I modified the code adding using statement:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var ab = context.Auctions.First();
            (...)
        }
```

But the first line gives me an exception of other kind:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: No database providers are configured.
>   Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your
>   DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up
>   services.

Is this the right way and how to configure the OnConfiguring? 
My confiuration in Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

Also, I have everything configured as it was said in the answer of the question that was supposted to solve my problem, but it still doesn't work and I suspect ajax.

Comment: I think that this should be a great implementation on SignalR instead....

Comment: It's seems to premature context disposition error.

Comment: `async void` seems very very wrong in this scenario. Not that it's related to your error, but it's bad. How are you instantiating `_context` and `_userManager`? They're likely disposing themselves before this method returns.

Comment: You need to wrap your dbcontext calls in a using statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737 - garbage collection is getting you.

Comment: @Jordan I edited my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070086/no-database-providers-are-configured-ef7

Comment: @Jordan I have everything whats in that question's answer added to my solution and it works fine with the controller's context, just when I'm creating a new one there is this exception

Comment: check you `vm` is valid or not.

Comment: @Hadee it is valid

Comment: It's seems like you have no configuration for your DbContext on Startup class, Have you checked this ?

Comment: @H.Herzl i added my configuration for DbCOntext in Startup

Comment: Can you show please?

Comment: @H.Herzl i edited my question

Comment: Have you tried add the db context instance to controller's scope ? If you want more help, I need to see your code implementation because as you said, everything looks fine.